# Unable to run FB.logout()

Tags: javascript, facebook, angular

I know this question has been asked time and again, but I can't seem to be able to make it work based on the common solution.

Anyhow, the problem is that whenever I run FB.logout(), then the following exception is displayed:

```
Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/home.php' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.
```

I tried to add the website URL to the application's `developers.facebook.com`'s configuration, and its' corresponding Facebook Sign In Configuration.

I'm running my application on `https://localhost:4200`, and the same URL has beed added to both Facebook configurations. The only difference that I've been able to detect is that a `/` is added at the end.

The code I'm using:

Controller:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function (result) {
  if (result.authResponse) {
    FB.logout(function(response) {
    });
  }
});
```

JS file:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
  FB.init({
    appId: '{{fb.api.appId}}',
    xfbml: true,
    version: 'v2.8',
    oauth: true
  });
};
if (typeof(FB) !== 'undefined' && FB !== null ) {
  window.fbAsyncInit();
}

(function (d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {
    return;
  }
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

I should also mention a Web platform has been established for this project.

Thanks in advance for any help provided!

All the best,

Alejandro

Comment: So where do frames come into play, in your angular app ...?

Comment: Found a solution yet?